# Change content of HTML element (div) for few seconds

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I have a function which executes on `click` event from a button. After it clicked it displays me my message "Email was send!" in place of form.

After 5 seconds this message disappears and there is nothing left. How can I set the original content back to `div` after 5 seconds? Following is my snippet.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "Email was send!";
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('form').style.display = 'none';
    }, 5000);
}
```

I want to display my message for 5 seconds then back to original form content.

Comment: You should be stay on your form. Just add the Success message on your page and disappear it after 5 seconds.

Comment: You should instead have the success message in a separate element, and hide one and show the other, rather than temporarily replacing the form.

Comment: Did you try to store your innerHTML before assigning a new value? Then after all you can set your innerHTML again with this stored value instead of setting display none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the innerHTML into a variable first and then set it back after. Here's what I mean:

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = document.getElementById("form")
  var originalContent = form.innerHTML
  form.innerHTML = "Email was sent"
  setTimeout(function() {
    form.innerHTML = originalContent
  }, 5000)
}
```

There's no need to set the display to none, this will hide the form completely.

Comment: Try again, I erroneously had a capital 'F' for from inside the timeout. I have corrected this.

Comment: You could add a span around your new content and add a class like so: form.innerHTML = "<span class='myClass'>Email was sent</span>"

Comment: Well, there is no code in here to send an email, if you have a separate function for that, you should call it from this function.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you're asking, you simply need to store the contents of the form before replacing it with the email message, then restore them in the timeout. Setting the form's display to none just hides the element without changing the contents.

e.g.

```
function myFunction() {
    var old_html = document.getElementById("form").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "Email was send!";
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = old_html;
    }, 5000);
}
```

---

Although this should solve your problem, I would recommend putting the email message in a separate element and hiding/showing as necessary. It doesn't really make sense to replace the form contents if you're just going to put them back in five seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting display none of your form button.

Comment: Please elaborate or put it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
        var originalContent = document.getElementById("form").innerHTML;
        document.getElementById("form").innerHTML = "Email was send!";
        setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById('form').innerHTML = originalContent;
                 }, 5000);
     }
</script>
```